# Using "I fell in love with .." in everyday communication

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Can someone please explain to me which is the correct statement.
If I communicate with a friend and want to tell him that I fell in love with a  girl.
I think that "I fell in love with .." is more often used in books.
Or is this expression appropriate for modern colloquial speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *fall in love* in both formal and informal contexts. Use *fall for* if you're looking for something informal. For example:

> They fell for each other instantly.

Source: [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fall-for)